# Gmail API User.Settings.SendAs Signature treating input as plain text only

Tags: html, api, gmail, signature

I am using the following Gmail API using the PHP Google API Client Library.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/patch

This is my code that executes the call:

```
$signature = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();
$signature->setSignature($this->signature);
$gmail->users_settings_sendAs->patch($this->email, $this->email, $signature);
```

I am passing a string value containing HTML code to update the signature.

When I update the signature using the above, it displays as plain text showing the HTML, as if it doesnt support HTML through the API method.

The API reference for the User.Settings.SendAs resource says the following about the signature parameter:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs#resource

> signature string  An optional HTML signature that is included in messages composed with this alias in the Gmail web UI.

So this seems to indicate that it supports HTML. We have tried VERY basic HTML like the following:

```
<em>Test</em>
```

It shows the above as is as plain text.

Can anyone help me to understand what are we doing wrong. We want to use this API to update the signature with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

So we found the issue. Our controller was using htmlentities on the html String which is what was causing it to be treated as plain text.